# Keep getting [$injector:modulerr] Error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am following the phoneCat tutorial[https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/] and decide to create a similar structured app. but I keep getting $injector:modulerr Error when I try to include a module I created. 
[files are arranged like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu4Mg.png)

The way I started my app is use npm package http-sever with command http-server ...\app.

Another thing I noticed is that if I use http-server command directly(rather than npm start suggested in tutorial) to start app in the app folder it also gives me error message. I am now pretty confused about this.

This is my app.module.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dota2Hero', [
  'ngRoute',
  'core'
]);
```

If I remove 'core' from dependency array, the code compiles.

Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="dota2Hero">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dota2 Database</title>

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="core/hero/hero.module.js"></script>
    <script src="core/core.module.js"></script>  
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="core/hero/hero.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

and my core.module.js

```
'use strict';


angular.module('core',['core.hero']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order in which you load the references, load the core.module.js before loading app.module.js

```
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
     <script src="core/hero/hero.module.js"></script>
    <script src="hero-grid/hero-grid.module.js"></script>   
    <script src="core/core.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="core/hero/hero.service.js"></script>
    <script src="hero-grid/hero-grid.component.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed my code but same error still.

Comment: is hero module is used in app.module?

Comment: app.module depends on core.module, which depends on hero.module.

Comment: same error still. Thanks for helping me anyway. I am thinking if I miss something crucial. I already uploaded this app to git. https://github.com/Aozaki-Touko/webApplication-dota2hero

Comment: @YichenYue yeah i checked it, check the updated order. you are also missing the reference for ngResource. the above should work

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much sir.

Comment: sure no problem.